# overlapping genomic intervals and merging datasets

Tags: r

I want to do something similar to the solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101849/overlapping-genomic-ranges), where by I have two dataframes and I want to find regions that overlap, and then merge the corresponding data to the hits

```
>x1
  chr start stop CN
1   1    10  140  G
2   1   100 1000  G
3   1  1500 5000  L



>x2
  chr start stop gene
1   1     1  100    a
2   1   100  150    b
3   1   190 1000    c
4   1  1000 2000    d
5   1  2000 5000    e
```

I can find the regions that overlap with the following code:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr1 = with(x1, GRanges(chr, IRanges(start=start, end=stop)))
gr2 = with(x2, GRanges(chr, IRanges(start=start, end=stop)))

hits = findOverlaps(gr1, gr2)
```

with the hits showing the regions in x1 that overlap with x2 e.g:

```
> hits
Hits of length 8
queryLength: 3
subjectLength: 5
  queryHits subjectHits 
   <integer>   <integer> 
 1         1           1 
 2         1           2 
 3         2           1 
 4         2           2 
 5         2           3 
 6         2           4 
 7         3           4 
 8         3           5
```

What I would like to do instead would be have the output include both gene and CN info from x1 and x2. The output would look like this

```
 x1chr x1start x1stop x1CN x2chr x2start x2stop x2gene
1     1      10    140    g     1       1    100      a
2     1      10    140    g     1     100    150      b
3     1     100   1000    g     1       1    100      a
4     1     100   1000    g     1     100    150      b
5     1     100   1000    g     1     190   1000      c
6     1     100   1000    g     1    1000   2000      d
7     1    1500   5000    l     1    1000   2000      d
8     1    1500   5000    l     1    2000   5000      e
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `foverlaps` from `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(x1), start, stop)
setkey(setDT(x2), start, stop)
foverlaps(x2, x1)
#   chr start stop CN i.chr i.start i.stop gene
#1:   1    10  140  G     1       1    100    a
#2:   1   100 1000  G     1       1    100    a
#3:   1    10  140  G     1     100    150    b
#4:   1   100 1000  G     1     100    150    b
#5:   1   100 1000  G     1     190   1000    c
#6:   1   100 1000  G     1    1000   2000    d
#7:   1  1500 5000  L     1    1000   2000    d
#8:   1  1500 5000  L     1    2000   5000    e
```

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to find a very simple solutions. 
Using the code:

```
x<-cbind(x1[queryHits(hits),],x2[subjectHits(hits),])
```

this provides the desired as output

Answer (score 0):

If you are under system of linux or mac, you can install bedtools(http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).
And then use commands "intersectBed -a fileA.txt -b fileB.txt -wa -wb > youroutputfile.txt". You will get the result file with both dataframe A and dataframe B.
It would be much faster and popular to use bedtools to deal with high-throughput datasets.

Comment: Unfortunately my work insists we use windows. However, I have used bedtools before and Galaxy.org also has tools that allow this.