# Processing the input file based on range overlap

Tags: r, range, bioinformatics, overlap

I have a huge input file (a representative sample of which is shown below as `input`):

```
> input
           CT1           CT2           CT3
1 chr1:200-400  chr1:250-450  chr1:400-800
2 chr1:800-970  chr2:200-500  chr1:700-870
3 chr2:300-700 chr2:600-1000 chr2:700-1400
```

I want to process it by following some rules (described below) so that I get an `output` like:

```
 > output
              CT1 CT2 CT3
chr1:200-400    1   1   0
chr1:800-970    1   0   0
chr2:300-700    1   1   0
chr1:250-450    1   1   0
chr2:200-500    1   1   0
chr2:600-1000   0   1   1
chr1:400-800    0   0   1
chr1:700-870    0   1   1
chr2:700-1400   0   1   1
```

**Rules:**
Take every index (the first in this case is `chr1:200-400`), see if it overlap significantly with values in other column. From significantly I mean atleast 50% overlap of the range. If yes, write `1` below that column in which it exists, if not write `0`.

Now I explain how I got the output table. From our input we take 1st index input[1,1] which is `chr1:200-400`. As it exists in column 1 we will write 1 below it. Now we will check if this or an overlapping range exists in any other column. This value overlaps only with the first value (`chr1:250-450`) of the second column (`CT2`). Now we check if this overlap is significant or not. We know that range is 200 (chr1:200-400), the overlap with 2nd column value (which is chr1:250-450) is **150** (250-400). As this overlap of 150 is greater than the half (50% of original range = 100) of original range (200-400 = 200) **OR** overlapping range (250-450 = 200). We consider it an overlap and assign 1 below the column CT2 as well. As this range does not overlap with any value in `CT3`, we write 0 below `CT3`.
Similarly for row 9 of output. `chr2:700-1400` doesn't exist in `CT1` so write 0 below it. For `CT2` it overlaps with `chr2:600-1000`. The original range here is 700 (chr2:700-1400), half of it is 350. The overlap with `chr2:700-1000` of `CT2` is 300 (out of actual range chr2:600-1000). Now this overlap of 300 is not greater than the half of actual range 700 (chr2:700-1400 of CT3) but it is greater than the half of overlapping range 400 (chr2:600-1000 of CT2). Therefore, we consider it an overlap and write 1 below CT2. As this range actually exists in CT3, we write 1 below it as well.

Here are the dput of input and output:

```
> dput(input)
structure(list(CT1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("chr1:200-400", 
"chr1:800-970", "chr2:300-700"), class = "factor"), CT2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("chr1:250-450", 
"chr2:200-500", "chr2:600-1000"), class = "factor"), CT3 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("chr1:400-800", 
"chr1:700-870", "chr2:700-1400"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("CT1", 
"CT2", "CT3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
> dput(output)
structure(list(CT1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CT2 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), CT3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("CT1", "CT2", "CT3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("chr1:200-400", 
"chr1:800-970", "chr2:300-700", "chr1:250-450", "chr2:200-500", 
"chr2:600-1000", "chr1:400-800", "chr1:700-870", "chr2:700-1400"
))
```

Comment: Any hint about how to compare one value of a dataframe `df[1,1]` against the rest of the dataframe..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this requires many steps, and a number of concepts from the `data.table` package, most notably non-equi joins. I've commented the code throughout, and recommend running it step by step if you want more insight:

```
library(data.table)

input <- structure(list(CT1 = structure(1:3, .Label = 
  c("chr1:200-400", "chr1:800-970", "chr2:300-700"), class = 
  "factor"), CT2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("chr1:250-450", 
  "chr2:200-500", "chr2:600-1000"), class = "factor"), CT3 = 
  structure(1:3, .Label = c("chr1:400-800", "chr1:700-870", 
  "chr2:700-1400"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("CT1", 
  "CT2", "CT3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

output <- structure(list(CT1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  CT2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), CT3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
  0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("CT1", "CT2", "CT3"), class = 
  "data.frame", row.names = c("chr1:200-400", "chr1:800-970", 
  "chr2:300-700", "chr1:250-450", "chr2:200-500", "chr2:600-1000",
  "chr1:400-800", "chr1:700-870", "chr2:700-1400"))

# Builds a data.table by breaking a string like "chr1:300-700" into 
# three columns: chr, start, and end.
split_genomic_range <- function(str) {
  chr <- gsub(":.*", "", str)
  start <- gsub("-.*", "", gsub(".*:", "", str))
  end <- gsub(".*-", "", str)

  start <- as.numeric(start)
  end <- as.numeric(end)

  return(data.table(chr=chr, start=start, end=end))
}

# First break the input data.table into three new tables - we will need
# to perform non-equi joins of the index table (column CT1 in input) to
# the tables built from the other two columns.
ct1 <- split_genomic_range(input$CT1)
ct2 <- split_genomic_range(input$CT2)
ct3 <- split_genomic_range(input$CT3)

# Create an index table with all genomic ranges, then check for 
# overlaps in each of the three tables created from the input
# columns:
index_table <- unique(rbind(ct1, ct2, ct3))

# Returns entries from the index_table if they overlap > 50% any 
# entries in the lookup table or vice-versa
get_overlapping_ranges <- function(index_table, lookup_table) {
  # This function does two non-equi joins. First, it checks whether 
  # any entries in the index_table have a 50% overlap with any 
  # entries in  the lookup table. Second, it does the reverse, and  
  # checks whether any entries in the lookup_table have a 50% overlap 
  # with any entries in the index_table. This is required due to 
  # differing window sizes:
  # e.g. 0-20 significantly overlaps 10-100, but 10-100 does not 
  # significantly overlap 0-20.

  # We will need to create a "middle" column for each genomic range.
  # We will need to create copies of each table to do this, otherwise
  # they will end up with this new column as a side effect of the 
  # function call.
  index_copy <- copy(index_table)
  lookup_copy <- copy(lookup_table)

  index_copy[, middle := start + (end - start) * 0.5]
  lookup_copy[, middle := start + (end - start) * 0.5]

  # In the index_copy we will also need to create dummy columns for
  # the check. We need to do this so we can find the appropriate 
  # genomic window from the index table when we do the second  
  # non-equi join, otherwise the start and end columns will be 
  # clobbered. 
  index_copy[, start_index := start]
  index_copy[, end_index := end]

  # If the middle of a genomic range in the index table falls within 
  # a genomic range in the lookup table, then that genomic entry from 
  # the index table has a significant overlap with the corresponding 
  # in the lookup table
  index_overlaps <- index_copy[lookup_table, 
    on=.(chr, middle >= start, middle <= end),
    nomatch=0]

  # Test the reverse: does any entry in the lookup table 
  # significantly  overlap with any of the genomic windows in the 
  # index table?
  lookup_overlaps <- index_copy[lookup_copy,
    on=.(chr, start_index <= middle, end_index >= middle),
    nomatch=0]

  # Remove extra columns created by the non-equi join:
  index_overlaps <- index_overlaps[,.(chr, start, end)]
  lookup_overlaps <- lookup_overlaps[,.(chr, start, end)]

  # Combine results and remove any duplicates that arise, e.g. 
  # because a genomic window in the index_table significantly 
  # overlaps with multiple genomic windows in the lookup table, or 
  # because the overlap is significant in both comparisons (i.e. 
  # where both windows are the same size).
  overlaps <- unique(rbind(index_overlaps, lookup_overlaps))

  return(overlaps)
}

ranges_in_ct1 <- get_overlapping_ranges(index_table, ct1)
ranges_in_ct2 <- get_overlapping_ranges(index_table, ct2)
ranges_in_ct3 <- get_overlapping_ranges(index_table, ct3)

# Combine results, indicating which column each genomic range was 
# found to overlap:
overlaps <- rbind(
  CT1=ranges_in_ct1, CT2=ranges_in_ct2, CT3=ranges_in_ct3,
  idcol="input_column"
) 

# Recombine the chr, start, and end columns to the original format:
overlaps[, genomic_window := paste0(chr, ":", start, "-", end)]
overlaps[, c("chr", "start", "end") := NULL]

# Convert to the wide format, so that each input column either has a  
# 1 or 0 if the genomic window overlaps with 50% any other found in 
# that column
overlaps <- dcast(overlaps, genomic_window ~ input_column, 
                  fun.aggregate = length)

# Convert back to a data.frame:
overlaps <- as.data.frame(overlaps)
rownames(overlaps) <- overlaps$genomic_window
overlaps <- overlaps[,-1]

# Reorder so we can double check against the desired output:
overlaps <- overlaps[rownames(output),]
print(overlaps)
```

This will generate (almost) the same output you've provided:

```
              CT1 CT2 CT3
chr1:200-400    1   1   0
chr1:800-970    1   0   0
chr2:300-700    1   1   0
chr1:250-450    1   1   0
chr2:200-500    1   1   0
chr2:600-1000   0   1   1
chr1:400-800    0   0   1
chr1:700-870    0   0   1
chr2:700-1400   0   1   1
```

The only difference is that chr1:700-870 has a 0 in the CT2 column: this is because it actually doesn't overlap any of the genomic windows in CT2, the only other window on chromosome 1 was chr1:250-450.

Comment: Many thanks for such a detailed answer. Can you please help me making it generalized to an input column, rather than explicitly mentioning the column names. For example for the first part where we apply `split_genomic_range` can be modified as `for (i in 1:length(colnames(input))) {`
 `assign(paste(colnames(input[i])), split_genomic_range(input[,i]))
 }` But I am unable to do the same for `get_overlapping_ranges` function.