# Overlap join with start and end positions

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

Consider the following `data.table`s. The first defines a set of regions with start and end positions for each group 'x':

```
library(data.table)

d1 <- data.table(x = letters[1:5], start = c(1,5,19,30, 7), end = c(3,11,22,39,25))
setkey(d1, x, start)

#    x start end
# 1: a     1   3
# 2: b     5  11
# 3: c    19  22
# 4: d    30  39
# 5: e     7  25
```

The second data set has the same grouping variable 'x', and positions 'pos' within each group:

```
d2 <- data.table(x = letters[c(1,1,2,2,3:5)], pos = c(2,3,3,12,20,52,10))
setkey(d2, x, pos)

#    x pos
# 1: a   2
# 2: a   3
# 3: b   3
# 4: b  12
# 5: c  20
# 6: d  52
# 7: e  10
```

Ultimately I'd like to extract the rows in 'd2' where 'pos' falls within the range defined by 'start' and 'end', within each group `x`. The desired result is

```
#    x pos start  end
# 1: a   2     1    3
# 2: a   3     1    3
# 3: c  20    19   22
# 4: e  10     7   25
```

The start/end positions for any group `x` will never overlap but there may be gaps of values not in any region.

Now, I believe I should be using a rolling join. From what i can tell, I cannot use the "end" column in the join.

I've tried

```
d1[d2, roll = TRUE, nomatch = 0, mult = "all"][start <= end]
```

and got

```
#    x start end
# 1: a     2   3
# 2: a     3   3
# 3: c    20  22
# 4: e    10  25
```

which is the right set of rows I want; However "pos" has become "start" and the original "start" has been lost. Is there a way to preserve all the columns with the roll join so i could report "start", "pos", "end" as desired?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[Overlap joins](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/528) was  implemented with [commit 1375](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/cb6cacea6f8ed97e0355cbb737ed23803d2c4044) in [data.table v1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), and is available in the [current stable release, v1.9.4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). The function is called `foverlaps`. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> 29) `Overlap joins` [#528](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/528) is now here, finally!! Except for `type="equal"` and `maxgap` and `minoverlap` arguments, everything else is implemented. Check out `?foverlaps` and the examples there on its usage. This is a major feature addition to `data.table`.

Let's consider x, an interval defined as `[a, b]`, where `a <= b`, and y, another interval defined as `[c, d]`, where `c <= d`. The interval y is said to *overlap* x at all, iff `d >= a` **and** `c <= b` [1](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). And y is entirely contained *within* x, iff `a <= c,d <= b` [2](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html). For the different types of overlaps implemented, please have a look at `?foverlaps`.

Your question is a special case of an overlap join: in `d1` you have true physical intervals with `start` and `end` positions. In `d2` on the other hand, there are only positions (`pos`), not intervals. To be able to do an overlap join, we need to create intervals also in `d2`. This is achieved by creating an additional variable `pos2`, which is identical to `pos` (`d2[, pos2 := pos]`). Thus, we now have an interval in `d2`, albeit with identical *start* and *end* coordinates. This 'virtual, zero-width interval' in `d2` can then be used in `foverlap` to do an overlap join with `d1`:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.3
setkey(d1)
d2[, pos2 := pos]
foverlaps(d2, d1, by.x = names(d2), type = "within", mult = "all", nomatch = 0L)
#    x start end pos pos2
# 1: a     1   3   2    2
# 2: a     1   3   3    3
# 3: c    19  22  20   20
# 4: e     7  25  10   10
```

`by.y` by default is `key(y)`, so we skipped it. `by.x` by default takes `key(x)` if it exists, and if not takes `key(y)`. But a key doesn't exist for `d2`, and we can't set the columns from `y`, because they don't have the same names. So, we set `by.x` explicitly.

The *type of overlap* is *within*, and we'd like to have *all* matches, only if there is a match.

NB: `foverlaps` uses data.table's binary search feature (along with `roll` where necessary) under the hood, but some function arguments (types of overlaps, maxgap, minoverlap etc..) are inspired by the function `findOverlaps()` from the Bioconductor package [`IRanges`](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html), an excellent package (and so is [`GenomicRanges`](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html), which extends `IRanges` for Genomics).

---

So what's the advantage?

A benchmark on the code above on your data results in `foverlaps()` slower than Gabor's answer (Timings: Gabor's data.table solution = 0.004 vs foverlaps = 0.021 seconds). But does it really matter at this granularity?

What would be really interesting is to see how well it scales - in terms of both *speed* and *memory*. In Gabor's answer, we join based on the key column `x`. *And then* filter the results.

What if `d1` has about 40K rows and `d2` has a 100K rows (or more)? For *each row* in `d2` that matches `x` in `d1`, *all* those rows will be matched and returned, only to be filtered later. Here's an example of your Q scaled only slightly:

#### Generate data:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1L)
n = 20e3L; k = 100e3L
idx1 = sample(100, n, TRUE)
idx2 = sample(100, n, TRUE)
d1 = data.table(x = sample(letters[1:5], n, TRUE), 
                start = pmin(idx1, idx2), 
                end = pmax(idx1, idx2))

d2 = data.table(x = sample(letters[1:15], k, TRUE), 
                pos1 = sample(60:150, k, TRUE))
```

#### foverlaps:

```
system.time({
    setkey(d1)
    d2[, pos2 := pos1]
    ans1 = foverlaps(d2, d1, by.x=1:3, type="within", nomatch=0L)
})
# user  system elapsed 
#   3.028   0.635   3.745
```

This took ~ 1GB of memory in total, out of which `ans1` is 420MB. Most of the time spent here is on subset really. You can check it by setting the argument `verbose=TRUE`.

#### Gabor's solutions:

```
## new session - data.table solution
system.time({
    setkey(d1, x)
    ans2 <- d1[d2, allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=0L][between(pos1, start, end)]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 15.714   4.424  20.324
```

And this took a total of ~3.5GB.

I just noted that Gabor already mentions the memory required for intermediate results. So, trying out `sqldf`:

```
# new session - sqldf solution
system.time(ans3 <- sqldf("select * from d1 join 
            d2 using (x) where pos1 between start and end"))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 73.955   1.605  77.049
```

Took a total of ~1.4GB. So, it definitely uses less memory than the one shown above.

[The answers were verified to be identical after removing `pos2` from `ans1` and setting key on both answers.]

Note that this overlap join is designed with problems where `d2` doesn't necessarily have identical start and end coordinates (ex: genomics, the field where I come from, where `d2` is usually about 30-150 million or more rows).

---

`foverlaps()` is stable, but is still under development, meaning some arguments and names might get changed.

NB: Since I mentioned `GenomicRanges` above, it is also perfectly capable of solving this problem. It uses [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=interval+trees) under the hood, and is quite memory efficient as well. In my benchmarks on genomics data, `foverlaps()` is faster. But that's for another (blog) post, some other time.

Comment: Did you ever make that blog post? I'm attempting to overlap nearly every nucleotide in the human genome (scored for a relevant metric) with a set of ranges and I killed GRanges's findOverlaps after like four hours to start off on the foverlaps tangent. Having this a ready-made blog post with instructions would have saved me a lot of time today. :D

Answer (score 30):

`data.table v1.9.8+` has a new feature - *non-equi* joins. With that, this operation becomes even more straightforward:

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.8+
# no need to set keys on `d1` or `d2`
d2[d1, .(x, pos=x.pos, start, end), on=.(x, pos>=start, pos<=end), nomatch=0L]
#    x pos start end
# 1: a   2     1   3
# 2: a   3     1   3
# 3: c  20    19  22
# 4: e  10     7  25
```

Comment: would you mind adding memory-usage and timing for this approach

Comment: It's helpful to note here that x is referring to two things. The first x is the column "x" and the second x in x.pos refers to d2.

Comment: @RyanWardValverde Why is it necessary to include `pos=x.pos`? Say there are more columns in `d2` such as 'a' and 'b'. When selecting the columns; a and b don't need to be prefixed with x, however `pos` does. Furthermore if you don't prefix pos with x then `pos==start`. Do you know why that's expected?

Comment: Seems like a byproduct of the order of operations. Removing everything between the parens in the `j` position, i.e. `.(...)` gives us `d2[d1, on = .(x, pos>=start, pos<=end), nomatch = NULL]`, and yields columns named `pos` and `pos.1`, which correspond to `start` and `end`, which is unexpected behavior to me. This seems to indicate that the join is done first, and to access the `data.table` in the `x` position, it needs to be called explicitly.

Answer (score 25):

**1) sqldf** This is not data.table but complex join criteria are easy to specify in a straight forward manner in SQL:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * from d1 join d2 using (x) where pos between start and end")
```

giving:

```
  x start end pos
1 a     1   3   2
2 a     1   3   3
3 c    19  22  20
4 e     7  25  10
```

**2) data.table** For a data.table answer try this:

```
library(data.table)

setkey(d1, x)
setkey(d2, x)
d1[d2][between(pos, start, end)]
```

giving:

```
   x start end pos
1: a     1   3   2
2: a     1   3   3
3: c    19  22  20
4: e     7  25  10
```

Note that this does have the disadvantage of forming the possibly large intermeidate result `d1[d2]` which SQL may not do.  The remaining solutions may have this problem too.

**3) dplyr**  This suggests the corresponding dplyr solution.  We also use `between` from data.table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table) # between

d1 %>% 
   inner_join(d2) %>% 
   filter(between(pos, start, end))
```

giving:

```
Joining by: "x"
  x start end pos
1 a     1   3   2
2 a     1   3   3
3 c    19  22  20
4 e     7  25  10
```

**4) merge/subset** Using only the base of R:

```
subset(merge(d1, d2), start <= pos & pos <= end)
```

giving:

```
   x start end pos
1: a     1   3   2
2: a     1   3   3
3: c    19  22  20
4: e     7  25  10
```

**Added** Note that the data table solution here is much faster than the one in the other answer:

```
dt1 <- function() {
 d1 <- data.table(x=letters[1:5], start=c(1,5,19,30, 7), end=c(3,11,22,39,25))
 d2 <- data.table(x=letters[c(1,1,2,2,3:5)], pos=c(2,3,3,12,20,52,10))
 setkey(d1, x, start)
 idx1 = d1[d2, which=TRUE, roll=Inf] # last observation carried forwards

 setkey(d1, x, end)
 idx2 = d1[d2, which=TRUE, roll=-Inf] # next observation carried backwards

 idx = which(!is.na(idx1) & !is.na(idx2))
 ans1 <<- cbind(d1[idx1[idx]], d2[idx, list(pos)])
}

dt2 <- function() {
 d1 <- data.table(x=letters[1:5], start=c(1,5,19,30, 7), end=c(3,11,22,39,25))
 d2 <- data.table(x=letters[c(1,1,2,2,3:5)], pos=c(2,3,3,12,20,52,10))
 setkey(d1, x)
 ans2 <<- d1[d2][between(pos, start, end)]
}

all.equal(as.data.frame(ans1), as.data.frame(ans2))
## TRUE

benchmark(dt1(), dt2())[1:4]
##     test replications elapsed relative
##  1 dt1()          100    1.45    1.667  
##  2 dt2()          100    0.87    1.000  <-- from (2) above
```

Comment: I do appreciate your comprehensiveness. I just really wanted something to take advantage of the optimized tree search implemented in the data.table roll join. Thanks for the `sqldf` suggestion. I was accustomed to writing joins like `sqldf("select * from d1 join d2 on d1.x==d2.x and d2.pos>=d1.start and d2.pos<=d1.end")` in SQL Server which were nice when you could add indexes to table. I think this may avoid creating a full outer join in memory (but didn't test)

Comment: However, note that the data.table code here is shorter and faster.

Comment: You are right, `between` is faster. I also tested `d1[d2, roll=T, nomatch=0, mult="all"][start<=end]` with your harness and was close to between. It just goes to show you have to test everything because you never know what will be faster. Thanks for taking the time to check these. Very interesting. Maybe when @Arun implements "range join" in data.table he can make it faster.

Comment: Could you explain how "d1[d2][between(pos, start, end)]" works, please?

Comment: `d1[d2]` joins `d1` and `d2` along `x` and `[between(...)]` selects those rows for which the `between(...)` is TRUE.

Answer (score 9):

Overlap joins are available in `dplyr 1.1.0` via the function `join_by`.

With `join_by`, you can do overlap join with `between`, or manually with `>=` and `<=`:

```r
library(dplyr)
inner_join(d2, d1, by = join_by(x, between(pos, start, end)))
#  x pos start end
#1 a   2     1   3
#2 a   3     1   3
#3 c  20    19  22
#4 e  10     7  25
```

```r
inner_join(d2, d1, by = join_by(x, pos >= start, pos <= end))
#  x pos start end
#1 a   2     1   3
#2 a   3     1   3
#3 c  20    19  22
#4 e  10     7  25
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `fuzzyjoin` :

```
result <- fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(d1, d2, 
                           by = c('x', 'pos' = 'start', 'pos' = 'end'),
                           match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))
result

#  x.x     pos x.y   start   end
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         2 a         1     3
#2 a         3 a         1     3
#3 c        20 c        19    22
#4 e        10 e         7    25
```

Since `fuzzyjoin` returns all the columns we might need to do some cleaning to keep the columns that we want.

```
library(dplyr)
result %>% select(x = x.x, pos, start, end)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  x       pos start   end
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         2     1     3
#2 a         3     1     3
#3 c        20    19    22
#4 e        10     7    25
```