# Searching for values in one data frame using another

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have 2 data frames: `dfA` and `dfB`

I would like to be able to extract whole rows from `dfB` that meet criteria based on `dfA`

Example:

```
if (dfA$colA == dfB$colB) && (dfB$colC >= dfA$colD) && 
  (dfB$colC <= dfA$colE) { print rows from dfB }
```

The values from the 1st column in `dfA` need to be an exact match for the 2nd column in `dfB`

AND

the values from column 3 in `dfB` need to fall within a range set by columns 4 and 5 in `dfA`.

The output should be the rows from `dfB` that meet these criteria.

Comment: This sounds like a rolling join. Try looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window. Bur normally questions are much easier to answer with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output.

Comment: I would suggest you provide example data sets and your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure with R but I guess it must be similar to Pandas: Just create three boolean masks, one for each criteria, than combine those to an overall-mask.

Example:
1stBoolMask = dfB[dfA$colA == dfB$colB] -> Something like ( 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 ... ) returns. A "1" stands for every matching entry in dfB.

2ndBoolMask = ...

3rdBoolMask = ...

-> OverallMask = 1stBoolMask & 2ndBoolMask & 3rdBoolMask

Then apply this one to dfB and you should be done. The "1s" in the resulting filter represent the matching lines of dfB.

Comment: thanks for the help! your suggestion of "1stBoolMask = dfB[dfA$colA == dfB$colB]" and adding a which() command to it has worked a treat!   newdf <- dfB[which(dfA$colA==dfB$colB & dfB$colC >= dfA$colD & dfB$colC <= dfA$colE),]