# How to merge two dataframes in R based on two conditions, matching column and within a range?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1:

name  start   end       prop
NC12     0   15000     62.62667  
NC12   100   15100     62.62667  
NC14     0   15000     62.66000   
NC14   100   15100     62.62000   
NC14   200   15200     62.67333   
NC15     0   15000     62.66667
```

df2:

```
name    SNPs    type 
NC12    1569    A 
NC12    15002   B
NC12    15007   C
NC14    15165   A
NC14    15187   D
NC15    1572    B
```

I want to append the value of column `type` from `df2` to `df1` if `SNPs` in `df2` fall within the range of `start` and `end` in `df1` and values in `name` matches in both. In cases where `SNPs` fall within multiple ranges, append `type` value separated by a delimiter.

If there are no values to be assigned to row in `df1` just add `null`.

so the result of processing two dataframes will be:

```
df3:

name  start   end       prop     type
NC12     0   15000     62.62667  A
NC12   100   15100     62.62667  A,B
NC14     0   15000     62.66000  null 
NC14   100   15100     62.62000  null
NC14   200   15200     62.67333  null 
NC15     0   15000     62.66667  B
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Arun has published an update to pkg:data.table that should be helpful if efficiency is needed. Otherwise you should look at the bioc-package `IRanges`.

Comment: Specifically look at rolling joins with data.table. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window