# data frame lookup value in range and return different column

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have two data frames and wish to use the value in one (`DF1$pos`) to search through two columns in DF2 (DF2start, DF2end) and if it falls within those numbers, return `DF2$name`

***DF1***

```
ID   pos  name
chr   12
chr  542
chr  674
```

***DF2***

```
ID   start   end   annot
chr      1   200      a1
chr    201   432      a2
chr    540  1002      a3
chr   2000  2004      a4
```

so in this example I would like DF1 to become

```
ID   pos  name
chr   12    a1
chr  542    a3
chr  674    a3
```

I have tried using merge and intersect but do not know how to use an `if` statement with a logical expression in them.

The data frames should be coded as follows,

```
DF1  <- data.frame(ID=c("chr","chr","chr"),
               pos=c(12,542,672),
               name=c(NA,NA,NA))

DF2  <- data.frame(ID=c("chr","chr","chr","chr"),
               start=c(1,201,540,200),
               end=c(200,432,1002,2004),
               annot=c("a1","a2","a3","a4"))
```

Comment: I didn't vote this question down but I think whoever did so was because you didn't put your data frames in R format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `foverlaps` from the "data.table" package.

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(DF1)
DT2 <- data.table(DF2)
setkey(DT2, ID, start, end)
DT1[, c("start", "end") := pos]  ## I don't know if there's a way around this step...
foverlaps(DT1, DT2)
#     ID start  end annot pos i.start i.end
# 1: chr     1  200    a1  12      12    12
# 2: chr   540 1002    a3 542     542   542
# 3: chr   540 1002    a3 674     674   674
foverlaps(DT1, DT2)[, c("ID", "pos", "annot"), with = FALSE]
#     ID pos annot
# 1: chr  12    a1
# 2: chr 542    a3
# 3: chr 674    a3
```

---

As mentioned by @Arun in the comments, you can also use `which = TRUE` in `foverlaps` to extract the relevant values:

```
foverlaps(DT1, DT2, which = TRUE)
#    xid yid
# 1:   1   1
# 2:   2   3
# 3:   3   3
DT2$annot[foverlaps(DT1, DT2, which = TRUE)$yid]
# [1] "a1" "a3" "a3"
```

Comment: @Arun would there be a `dplyr` way to achieve this ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré, no overlap joins, but using `between()` - check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24480301/559784). It materialises the entire join and then filters.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `IRanges`

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("IRanges")
library(IRanges)
DF1N <- with(DF1, IRanges(pos, pos))
DF2N <- with(DF2, IRanges(start, end))
DF1$name <- DF2$annot[subjectHits(findOverlaps(DF1N, DF2N))]
DF1
#   ID pos name
#1 chr  12   a1
#2 chr 542   a3
#3 chr 674   a3
```

Comment: Nice. Using `GenomicRanges` package might be more relevant here though, as `IRanges` only deals with ranges (without identifiers). Or you've to use RangesList I think, but GRanges is much more convenient. The Q indicates only one chromosome, but I doubt it's the case in the real data set.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the info.  I don't have the `GenomicRanges` installed.  Will check it.

Comment: @Arun Could you add that as a separate answer?

Comment: thanks @Arun, i think the GenomicRanges is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This `dplyr' solution works similar to the range lookup in Excel.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(DF1, DF2, join_by(closest(pos > start)))
```