# loop through a file in R and select values based on a range

Tags: r

I have a file called 'genes' with 4300 lines that looks like

```
Gene_id  chr  start   stop              
GeneA chr1  10  1000                 
GeneB chr1  2300  7000                     
GeneC chr1 10000 13577
```

and another file called 'bases' (~100,000 lines) and looks like

```
Chr Bases          
chr1 160           
chr1 157             
chr1 8500           
chr1 2200
```

I want to produce a file that keeps the bases that fall into the range between start and stop for each gene

so output would look like

```
Chr Bases             
chr1 160            
chr1 157
```

I have tried this function but it only gives me back the first entry four times:

```
methC <- apply(bases,1,function(a){
my_bases <- bases[bases[1]==genes$chr & bases[2]>=genes$start & bases[2]<=genes$stop,]
result <- my_bases[,2]
return(result)
})

>methC
# 160 160 160
```

so I'm missing base 157 and 160 is duplicated 4 times.

If I use

```
b <- bases[which(bases[1]==genes$chr & bases[2]>=genes$start & bases[2]<=genes$stop),]
> b
 #  Chr Bases
#chr1   160
```

I'm still missing 157, but maybe that is due to the order.

However if I try using my real and much larger files with this 'which' function I get back an empty data.frame

```
> b
Chr        Base       
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

, so that's why I thought a function would be better to handle large datasets.

Comment: May be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619381/data-frame-lookup-value-in-range-and-return-different-column or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748535/finding-overlapping-ranges-between-two-interval-data/19752720#19752720

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window/25655497#25655497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the data table library:

```
library("data.table")

# Read the data from file
genes <- data.table(read.csv("genes.csv"))
bases <- data.table(read.csv("bases.csv"))

# Define the columns that are used to join the two tables
setkey(genes, chr)
setkey(bases, Chr)

# The first line joins the two tables, and the second line
# filters the result to keep only those that match and defines
# the columns that are to be shown in the output. Note the need
# to take care with capitalisation and the reserved word 'stop'
genes[bases, allow.cartesian = TRUE][
  Bases >= start & Bases <= `stop`, list(Chr = chr, Bases)]
```

Which produces this result:

```
    Chr Bases
1: chr1   160
2: chr1   157
```

Comment: You can use `fread()` to read in the file. And `foverlaps()` to perform overlapping range joins.