# Matching columns from a data frame (csv file with the columns of another dataframe csv file and add new colums

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, bioinformatics, matching

I got two big data frames(csv format), one (df1) has this structure

```
chromName fragStart fragEnd fragLength leftFragEndLength rightFragEndLength
   Chr1     176         377            202          202                202
   Chr1     472         746            275          275                275
   Chr1     1276        1382            107         107                107
   Chr1     1581        1761            181         173                  4
   Chr1     1890        2080            191          93                 71
```

The other (df2) includes the results for 5'target_id_start 5'target_id_end and 3'target_id_start,3'target_id_end **together** and it looks like this

```
    Chr target_id_start target_id_end tot_counts uniq_counts est_counts
1  Chr1        10000016      10000066          0           0          0
2  Chr1        10000062      10000112          0           0          0
3  Chr1        10000171      10000221          0           0          0
4  Chr1        10000347      10000397          0           0          0
5  Chr1         1000041       1000091          0           0          0
```

what I'm trying to do is to check if the column target_id_start and target_id_end **is between or equal** with the columns fragStart and fragEnd. If this is true then  i want to write the columns tot_counts uniq_counts est_counts in the first file df1. This will be true for 5'target_id_start 5'target_id_end and 3'target_id_start,3'target_id_end and the result to be like that

```
chromName fragStart fragEnd fragLength leftFragEndLength rightFragEndLength tot_counts5' uniq_counts5' est_counts5' tot_counts3' uniq_counts3' est_counts3'
    Chr1     176         377            202          202                202            0           0          0            0           0          0 
    Chr1     472         746            275          275                275            0           0          0            0           0          0
    Chr1     1276        1382            107         107                107            0           0          0            0           0          0
    Chr1     1581        1761            181         173                  4            0           0          0            0           0          0
    Chr1     1890        2080            191          93                 71            0           0          0            0           0          0
```

Do you know any good way to do this in R ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You may need to check `findOverlaps` from `library(IRanges)` or `foverlaps` from `library(data.table)` May be this link give some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619381/data-frame-lookup-value-in-range-and-return-different-column or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748535/finding-overlapping-ranges-between-two-interval-data/19752720#19752720

Comment: Both DFs are of equal size and each row in one corresponds to the row in other?

Comment: No the DFs are not of equal size and each row doesn't correspond to the row in other!

Comment: Perhaps you should simplify your example. Is the question to search if some interval of two numerics in df1 matches the interval of two numerics in df2? And then on every match write values from df2 to df1? Clutter of long column names kinda makes it lose the essence of question.

Comment: its something like that. If for example  fragStart<=target_id_start<=fragEnd or the same for target_id_end then on every match write values from df2 to df1. The number and names doesn’t help you are right. generally i want the numerics from df1 to be part of the two numerics of df2 or matches the intervals of the two numerics in df2. when this is true write values from df2 to df1

Comment: You might want to look at the function `cut` -- it takes a list of breaks (`df1`) and lets you encode which rows belong to which cut.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I really hate loops, the best I can offer is:

```
a <- data.frame(x = c(1,10,100), y = c(2, 20, 200))
b <- data.frame(x = c(1.5, 30, 90, 150), y = c(1.6, 50, 101, 170), z = c("a","b","c", "d"))

a$z <= NA

for(i in 1:length(a$x)){
  temp <- which((b$x >= a$x[i] & b$x <= a$y[i]) | (b$y >= a$x[i] & b$y <= a$y[i]))
  a$z[i] <- ifelse(length(temp) > 0, temp, NA) 
}
```

As an example - loop writes row index of data frame b where interval in a corresponds to interval in b. Further on you can write a loop where it takes these row indices and writes corresponding values to some other column.

This might give you some idea. But this is not efficient on large data sets. Hope it inspires you to proper solution. Not a workaround such as mine.