# How to extract all columns when using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
```

I am trying to do this.

```
wd <- structure(list(Year = c(2006L, 2006L, 2006L), day = c(361L, 361L, 
360L), hour = c(14L, 8L, 8L), mint = c(30L, 0L, 30L), valu1 = c(0.5, 
0.3, 0.4), Date = structure(c(1167229800, 1167206400, 1167121800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("Year", 
"day", "hour", "mint", "valu1", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")

wg <- c("2006/12/27 14:23:59", "2006/12/27 16:47:59", "2006/12/27 19:12:00")
w <- c("0.4", "0.2", "0.5")
wf=data.frame(wg,w)
wg <- as.POSIXct(wf$wg, format = "%Y/%m/%d %T", tz = "UTC") 
WG <- data.table(start = wg, end = wg)
setkey(WG)
## Do the same for `wd` adding +/- 30 minutes 
setDT(wd)[, `:=`(start = Date - 1800L, end = Date + 1800L)]
## Run foverlaps and extract the match `valu1` column
foverlaps(wd, WG, nomatch = 0L)[, .(wdDate = Date, valu1, WGDate = start)]
                    wdDate valu1              WGDate
   1: 2006-12-27 14:30:00   0.5 2006-12-27 14:23:59
```

As you can see in the final results only `valu1` was extracted from `wd` but I would like also to extract the corresponding values from `w` in `wf`.

So I want something like this:

```
                     wdDate valu1              WGDate      w
    1: 2006-12-27 14:30:00   0.5 2006-12-27 14:23:59      0.4
```

Any idea is welcome.

Real data:

```
  head(wf)
       date1  date2        date3n               wg         w    whyt
1     <NA> 2003-01-01      <NA>                <NA>        NA   NA
2     <NA> 2003-01-02      <NA>                <NA>        NA   NA
3     <NA> 2003-01-03      <NA> 2003/01/03 10:30:00 0.2137352 0.34
4     <NA> 2003-01-04      <NA>                <NA>        NA   NA
```

Facing a problem here:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[In my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30150902/3001626) I've created `WG` because you provided `wg` as a single vector. If you already have a data set called `wf`, this whole proccess is not needed. You just need to adjust `wf` correctly and then run `foverlaps`. In other words, forget about `WG` and do the following

```
setDT(wf)[, wg := as.POSIXct(wg, format = "%Y/%m/%d %T", tz = "UTC")]
wf[, `:=`(start = wg, end = wg)]
setkey(wf, start, end)
setDT(wd)[, `:=`(start = Date - 1800L, end = Date + 1800L)]

foverlaps(wd, wf, nomatch = 0L)[, .(wdDate = Date, valu1, WGDate = start, w)]
#                 wdDate valu1              WGDate   w
# 1: 2006-12-27 14:30:00   0.5 2006-12-27 14:23:59 0.4
```

Comment: I've added ````setDT(wd)[, `:=`(start = Date - 1800L, end = Date + 1800L)]```` back, I thought you already did that line. Everything up until (including) `wf=data.frame(wg,w)` is the same as in your post so I didn't repost it again.

Comment: Which column has NAs? `wg`?

Comment: `w` doesn't matter because it is not being joined on. Try removing `NA`s from `wf` using `wf <- na.omit(wf, by = "wg")` and then run `foverlaps`

Comment: The code doesn't search for *exactly*  +-30, it takes everything within that range exactly like you need. There is a `mult = "all"` argument that you can add to `foverlaps` but this is should be already the default. Can you please provide a reproducible example and show what would you expect to get? I'm starting to wonder though if you trying to match `wf` to `wd` ranges or the other way around.

Comment: Sorry, do `wf <- na.omit(wf, cols = "wg")` (Use `cols` instead of `by`. I wrote the code without testing in my previous comment).

Comment: If you have *real* `NA`s, `wf <- na.omit(wf, cols = "wg")` will work. For your second question, you can calculate means after words. It is a very simple aggregation task using `data.table`.

Comment: Per your edit, you want remove one row, or to assign the average to both rows?

Comment: Try `unique(res[, valu1 := mean(valu1), by = WGDate], by = "WGDate")`