# fill a data.table based on value in another data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I'm very new to `data.table` but would like to solve my problem with it, as I have the feeling it would be 1000 times faster than with "regular" data.frames.

Here is my problem:

**What I have:**

2 data.tables `dt1` and `dt2` like so:

```
dt1 <- data.table(SID=paste0("S", 1:15), Chromo=rep(1:3, e=5), PP=rep(1:5, 3), P1=0, P2=0, P3=0)
set.seed(17)
dt2 <- data.table(PID=rep(paste0("P", 1:3), c(2, 6, 3)), Chr=c(1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3), start= c(1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2), end=c(3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5), val=rnorm(11))
```

**What I want:**

Fill `dt1` with `dt2[, val]` in the right column, based on `dt2[, PID]` and the right lines, based on `dt1[, Chromo]`=`dt2[, Chr]` and `dt1[, PP]` in between `dt2[, start]` and `dt2[, end]`.

**What I do right now:** *(which doesn't make me proud, to say the least...)*

```
# preparing the tables, computing dt1 rows indices
dt2[, numcol:=(1:ncol(dt1))[match(dt2[,PID], colnames(dt1))]]
setkey(dt2, Chr, start, end)
setkey(dt1, Chromo, PP)
ind_start <- dt1[dt2[,.(Chr, start)], which=T]
ind_end <- dt1[dt2[,.(Chr, end)], which=T]
dt2[,c("ind_start", "ind_end"):=list(ind_start, ind_end)]

# and feeling I'm that close but can't conclude with `data.table` so doing this "lame" `for` loop with `data.frames`.......................
df1 <- as.data.frame(dt1)
df2 <- as.data.frame(dt2)
nr_seg <- nrow(df2)
for(i in 1:nr_seg){
    df1[df2[i,"ind_start"]:df2[i,"ind_end"], df2[i,"numcol"]] <- df2[i, "val"]
}
```

***The input tables and desired output (except I'd like a `data.table`)***:

```
dt1
    # SID Chromo PP P1 P2 P3
 # 1:  S1      1  1  0  0  0
 # 2:  S2      1  2  0  0  0
 # 3:  S3      1  3  0  0  0
 # 4:  S4      1  4  0  0  0
 # 5:  S5      1  5  0  0  0
 # 6:  S6      2  1  0  0  0
 # 7:  S7      2  2  0  0  0
 # 8:  S8      2  3  0  0  0
 # 9:  S9      2  4  0  0  0
# 10: S10      2  5  0  0  0
# 11: S11      3  1  0  0  0
# 12: S12      3  2  0  0  0
# 13: S13      3  3  0  0  0
# 14: S14      3  4  0  0  0
# 15: S15      3  5  0  0  0

dt2
  # PID Chr start end         val
 # 1:  P2   1     1   2 -0.23298702
 # 2:  P1   1     1   3 -1.01500872
 # 3:  P2   1     4   5 -0.81726793
 # 4:  P3   2     2   3  0.25523700
 # 5:  P2   2     2   4  0.77209084
 # 6:  P3   2     4   5  0.36658112
 # 7:  P2   3     1   1 -0.16561194
 # 8:  P1   3     1   4 -0.07963674
 # 9:  P2   3     2   3  0.97287443
# 10:  P3   3     2   5  1.18078924
# 11:  P2   3     4   5  1.71653398

df1
   # SID Chromo PP          P1         P2        P3
# 1   S1      1  1 -1.01500872 -0.2329870 0.0000000
# 2   S2      1  2 -1.01500872 -0.2329870 0.0000000
# 3   S3      1  3 -1.01500872  0.0000000 0.0000000
# 4   S4      1  4  0.00000000 -0.8172679 0.0000000
# 5   S5      1  5  0.00000000 -0.8172679 0.0000000
# 6   S6      2  1  0.00000000  0.0000000 0.0000000
# 7   S7      2  2  0.00000000  0.7720908 0.2552370
# 8   S8      2  3  0.00000000  0.7720908 0.2552370
# 9   S9      2  4  0.00000000  0.7720908 0.3665811
# 10 S10      2  5  0.00000000  0.0000000 0.3665811
# 11 S11      3  1 -0.07963674 -0.1656119 0.0000000
# 12 S12      3  2 -0.07963674  0.9728744 1.1807892
# 13 S13      3  3 -0.07963674  0.9728744 1.1807892
# 14 S14      3  4 -0.07963674  1.7165340 1.1807892
# 15 S15      3  5  0.00000000  1.7165340 1.1807892
```

Comment: You could use `foverlaps`. How do you decide in which `Pi` column the values have to go?

Comment: @Roland, thanks, I don't know this function, I'll take a look at it. As for `Pi`, the `Pi` in `PID` column of `dt2` has to match the name of the column in `dt1`

Comment: You may find [**this Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window) a useful starting point. Seems like your 'PP' column corresponds to the 'pos' column in that post. I find the 'updated answer' by @Arun very nice.

Comment: @Henrik, thanks again, I'm indeed reading all the Q/A and, yes, PP stands for "Physical Position" and Chr/Chromo for "Chromosome" ;-)

Comment: @CathG I realized that my wording "Possible duplicate" perhaps was unfortunate. Thus, I just wanted to phrase my pointer to a hopefully helpful Q&A differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(SID=paste0("S", 1:15), Chromo=rep(1:3, e=5), PP=rep(1:5, 3), P1=0, P2=0, P3=0)
set.seed(17)
dt2 <- data.table(PID=rep(paste0("P", 1:3), c(2, 6, 3)), Chr=c(1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3), start= c(1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2), end=c(3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5), val=rnorm(11))

dt1[, PP1 := PP]
dt1[, c("P1", "P2", "P3") := NULL]


setkey(dt2, Chr, start, end)

setkey(dt1, Chromo, PP, PP1)

res <- foverlaps(dt1, dt2, type="within")
res[is.na(PID), PID := "P1"] #to ensure that dcast works if there is no match
res <- dcast.data.table(res, SID + Chromo + PP ~ PID, value.var = "val")
setkey(res, Chromo, PP)

#    SID Chromo PP          P1         P2        P3
# 1:  S1      1  1 -1.01500872 -0.2329870        NA
# 2:  S2      1  2 -1.01500872 -0.2329870        NA
# 3:  S3      1  3 -1.01500872         NA        NA
# 4:  S4      1  4          NA -0.8172679        NA
# 5:  S5      1  5          NA -0.8172679        NA
# 6:  S6      2  1          NA         NA        NA
# 7:  S7      2  2          NA  0.7720908 0.2552370
# 8:  S8      2  3          NA  0.7720908 0.2552370
# 9:  S9      2  4          NA  0.7720908 0.3665811
#10: S10      2  5          NA         NA 0.3665811
#11: S11      3  1 -0.07963674 -0.1656119        NA
#12: S12      3  2 -0.07963674  0.9728744 1.1807892
#13: S13      3  3 -0.07963674  0.9728744 1.1807892
#14: S14      3  4 -0.07963674  1.7165340 1.1807892
#15: S15      3  5          NA  1.7165340 1.1807892
```

Comment: thanks Roland for the answer. I do need the 0 where there are now `NAs` though (and you can just `setkey(res, Chromo, PP)` as it needs to be sorted this way) and yes, I do need all SID

Comment: For the exact output, you could do ```res <- foverlaps(dt1, dt2, type="within") ; res <- dcast.data.table(res, SID + Chromo + PP ~ PID, value.var = "val", fill = 0L)[, `NA` := NULL]```. Though not so pretty.

Comment: @CathG I've changed it to include `S6`.

Comment: @Roland thanks a lot for the edit. I'm facing problem with my real data, I get warning "Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'" with the `dcast` call and only have 1s and 0s in res for columns 4 to last

Comment: @CathG This means you have duplicated SID/Chromo/PP ID combinations. You need to decide how you want to handle that case. One possibility could be to aggregate the values with the mean. Another would be to add an additional column that makes the ID combination unique.

Comment: @Roland; Thanks (again) for your answer, I'm not supposed to have duplicated SID-Chromo-PP-PID combinations........ gonna work on that!