# Merge two data frames considering a range match between key columns

Tags: r, merge

I am a beginner in programming in R. I am at the moment trying to retrieve some site names from a dataframe containing the X and Y coordinates and site names and copy them into a different dataframe with specific points.

```
    FD <- matrix(data =c(rep(1, 500), rep(0, 500),
                     rnorm(1000, mean = 550000, sd=4000),
                     rnorm(1000, mean = 6350000, sd=20000), rep(NA, 1000)),
             ncol = 4, nrow = 1000, byrow = FALSE)
colnames(FD) <- c('Survival', 'X', 'Y', 'Site') 
FD <- as.data.frame(FD)

shpxt <- matrix(c(526654.7,526810.5 ,6309098,6309187,530405.4,530692,
                  6337699, 6338056,580432.7, 580541.9, 6380246,6380391,
                  585761.3, 585847.6, 6379665, 6379759, 584192.1, 584279.4,
                  6382358, 6382710, 583421.2, 583492.4, 6379356, 6379425,
                  532395.5, 532515.3 , 6336421, 6336587, 534694.6, 534791.2,
                  6335620, 6335740, 536749.8, 536957.5, 6337584, 6338130, 590049.6,
                  590419.4, 6372232, 6372432, 580443, 580756.5, 6386342, 6386473,
                  575263.9, 575413.7, 6380416, 6380530, 584625.1, 584753.9, 6381009,
                  6381335), ncol = 4, nrow = 13, byrow = TRUE)
sites <- c("Brandbaeltet", "Brusaa", "Granly", "Jerup Strand", "Knasborgvej",
           "Milrimvej", "Overklitten", "Oversigtsareal", "Sandmosen",
           "Strandby", "Troldkaer", "Vaagholt", "Videsletengen")
colnames(shpxt) <- c("Xmin", "Xmax", "Ymin", "Ymax")
shpxt <- as.data.frame(shpxt)
shpxt["Sites"] <- sites
```

My approach is using a nested for loop like this:

```
    tester <- function(FD, shpxt)
{ for (i in 1:nrow(FD)) for (j in 1:nrow(shpxt))         # Open Function
{ if (FD[i,2] >= shpxt[j,1] | FD[i,2] <= shpxt[j,2] &    # Open Loop
      FD[i,3] >= shpxt[j,3] | FD[i,3] <= shpxt[j,4])
{                                                        # Open Consequent
  FD[i,4]=shpxt[j,5]
  {break}
} else                                                  # Close Consequent
{FD[i,4] <- NA                                          # Open alternative
}                                                      # Close alternative
}                                                      # Close loop
}                                                      # Close function

tester(FD, shpxt)
```

In essence I want to search for which site the X and Y coordinates in FD fall into range and copy the sitename into FD$Site in row i.
When I run the loop on my real data I get the following error message:

```
test(FD, shpxt)
Error in if (FD[i, 2] >= shpxt[j, 1] | FD[i, 2] <= shpxt[j, 2] & FD[i,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

How do I get the loop to go from here to where the loop will be copying the desired sitename into my FD?

Kind Regards Thøger

Comment: Suggestion: change the question title to include something about geo coordinates or latitude and longitude

Comment: your identation is a mess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to merge two data frames considering a range match between key columns. Here are two solutions.

#### using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)

output <- sqldf("select * from FD left join shpxt 
                on (FD.X >= shpxt.Xmin and FD.X <= shpxt.Xmax and
                    FD.Y >= shpxt.Ymin and FD.Y <= shpxt.Ymax ) ")
```

#### using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

# convert your datasets in data.table
  setDT(FD) 
  setDT(shpxt)

output <- FD[shpxt, on = .(X >= Xmin , X <= Xmax,                # indicate x range
                           Y >= Ymin , Y <= Ymax), nomatch = NA, # indicate y range
             .(Survival, X, Y, Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax, Sites )]  # indicate columns in the output
```

There are different alternatives to solve this problem, as you will find it in other SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944460/get-a-variables-value-from-one-dataset-if-falling-in-a-range-defined-by-two-vari) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892241/merge-by-range-in-r-applying-loops).

ps. Keep in mind that `for loop` is not necessarily the best solution.

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thank you very much!
I'll try to be more exact when asking questions from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a failed attempt in base R -- perhaps someone can help correct

```
 getSite <- function(x, y) {
    return (shpxt[x >= shpxt['Xmin'] & x <= shpxt['Xmax'] &
                  y >= shpxt['Ymin'] & y <= shpxt['Ymax'] , "Sites"])
  }
```

test it

```
   p <- c(Survival=0, X=shpxt[2,1], Y=shpxt[2,3]) 
   getSite(p[['X']],p[['Y']])
```

returns correctly with

```
[1] "Brusaa"
```

However

```
FD$Site<-apply(FD, 1, function(point) {getSite(point[['X']], point[['Y']])})
```

fails with

Error in ``$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Site", value = character(0)) : 
    replacement has 0 rows, data has 1000