# How to mutate the new column in R based on two column values

Tags: r, datatable

I have two data frames. `df1` contains three columns such as.

```
location  start_position  end_position
 a_a1       2500            5500
 b_a1       5600            6500
 c_a1       7500            8900
```

while `df2` contains following column

```
Sample Position 
A1      2300
A2      5300
A3      7600
```

All i want is I want a third column in my df2 that states location from `df1` as in `df1`. If `df2$Position` value lies between `df1$start_position` and `df1$end_position` like below

```
Sample Position Location
A1      2300    a_a1
A2      5300    b_a1
A3      7600    c_a1
```

Comment: See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160231/16730940  and the linked threads from there,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlap join with start and end positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/overlap-join-with-start-and-end-positions)

Comment: two of the three values from your question aren't within the ranges, am I missing something?

Comment: And what about values like 5550?

Comment: Two more links that discuss merge-on-range: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64362881/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64539945/3358272

Comment: You used the [tag:datatable] tag, which is ambiguous and likely a little misleading. Do you mean [tag:data.table] for the `data.table` R package? Or [tag:dataframe], a language-agnostic tag for tabular data? Do you have preferences for `data.table`, `dplyr`, and/or base R?

Answer (score 0):

An inefficient approach is to create an vector as index.

```
pos_index <- vector()

for (i in seq_len(nrow(df1))) {
  pos_index[df1$start_position[i]:df1$end_position[i]] <- df1$location[i]
}

df2$Location <- pos_index[df2$Position]

df2
  Sample Position Location
1     A1     2300     <NA>
2     A2     5300     a_a1
3     A3     7600     c_a1
```

A1 is NA because 2300 is not in any locations. Could you please check your example again?