# match value to range

Tags: sql, r

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in R. I have it figured out in SQL but can't use similar code in SQL within R. I am trying to find the row from 1 df that a cell would match to the row of another df and return a cell of the matched row

```
SerialNumber <- c(42665757,42669446,42648708,42648737,42648776,42652387,42654674,42654990,42656751,42659593,42659618,42659902,42660026,42663819)
dfCard <- data.frame(SerialNumber)

StartSerial <- c(42618423,42624997,42625214,42625278,42642749,42647278,42674105,42675036,42677581,42691947,42695551,42701150,42704169,42719412,42724142,42724242,42724278,42725814,42726714,42800716)
StopSerial <- c(42624996,42625213,42625277,42642748,42647277,42674104,42675035,42677580,42691946,42695550,42701149,42704168,42719411,42724106,42724241,42724277,42725813,42726713,42800711,42801255)
Job <- c(56174,56235,56235,56235,56235,56237,56241,56230,56235,56235,56239,56240,56235,56235,56235,56235,56235,56242,56238,56248)
dfNumbers <- data.frame(Job,StartSerial,StopSerial)
```

These are the two closest solutions i have

```
sqldf(c("ALTER TABLE dfScore ADD jobb numeric"),
      c("SELECT Job FROM dfSerials WHERE StartSerial <= 'dfScore.SerialNumber' AND StopSerial >= 'dfScore.SerialNumber'"))

dfScore$Jobb <- ifelse(dfScore$SerialNumber >= dfSerials$StartSerial & dfScore$SerialNumber <= dfSerials$StopSerial,
                       dfSerials$Job,
                       '')
```

Ultimately, I am want the job column from the `dfNumbers` dataframe appeneded to the `dfCard` dataframe through matching the `dfCard$SerialNumber` to the range in the `dfNumbers$StartSerial`/`dfNumbers$StopSerial`.

Comment: ‘library(dplyr); dfCard |> left_join(dfNumbers, join_by(SerialNumber >= StartSerial, SerialNumber <= StopSerial))’?

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover, it's not that *"R likes the join"*, it's that your use of `dfScore$SerialNumber >= dfSerials$StartSerial` is fundamentally incorrect in any programming language. The operation you are trying to do here, whether in SQL or R or Python or Julia, is a merge/join. In this case, it is a range-based join that is not supported in base R, instead needing `dplyr`, `data.table`, `fuzzyjoin`, or `sqldf`.

Comment: Several (not-new) links that discuss non-equi/range-based joins: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64362881/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64539945/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37158839/3358272. Your question is a dupe of one of them, the first two have been recently updated to use `dplyr::join_by` (a relatively recent addition).