# rollapply in R for calculating cumulative observations in a time window

Tags: r

I´m looking for a solution in R to count the number of unique customers with an activity during a rolling time window.

The data is like:

```
ID Date
1 20230910
2 20230910
7 20230911
8 20230912
1 20230912
7 20230914
9 20230915
```

What I want is:

```
20230910 2
20230911 3
20230912 4
20230913 4
20230914 4
20230915 5
```

The function I´m trying to ute is:

```
rolling_counts <- rollapply(time_series, width = 7, FUN = sum(Date) length(unique(ID)), by = 1, align = "right", fill = NA)
```

I´m not getting it working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to add a function in the `FUN` argument of rollapply; a function is a `function` object, like `function(x) sum(x)`; which is not the case in your example

Comment: that said, there may be easier solutions; can you precise what's your rolling time window? in your example, it is the same as the length of your data, in which case you could just use `cumsum`; can the rolling window be lower?

Comment: For instance, something as simple as `cumsum(!duplicated(df$ID))` works in your case; or `ave(cumsum(!duplicated(df$ID)), df$Date, FUN = max)` if you want to collapse by Date

Comment: Many thanks, the time window is 7 days so a lot smaller than the window for the data frame. "FUN = function(x) length(unique(person_id)), by = 1, align = "right", fill = NA)" Is it a "count" function that I better use? Like this "FUN = count(Date) length(unique(ID)), by = 1, align = "right", fill = NA)"?

Comment: Your dates appear to be either integers or strings with `YYYYMMDD` encoded in them; if you care about "missing days", then you need to convert these to real `Date`-class objects. If you don't care about missing days, then we can ignore the fact that these look like dates and just treat them like an ID of sorts, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done as a "non-equi merge". Since we need to treat the date column like a real date, however, we need to convert it to the proper class:

```r
quux$Date <- as.Date(as.character(quux$Date), format = "%Y%m%d")
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
tibble(Date = seq(min(out$Date), max(out$Date), by = "day")) %>%
  mutate(From = Date-7) %>%
  full_join(quux, join_by(between(y$Date, x$From, x$Date))) %>%
  group_by(Date = Date.x) %>%
  summarize(count = n_distinct(ID))
# # A tibble: 6 × 2
#   Date       count
#   <date>     <int>
# 1 2023-09-10     2
# 2 2023-09-11     3
# 3 2023-09-12     4
# 4 2023-09-13     4
# 5 2023-09-14     4
# 6 2023-09-15     5
```

The first `tibble(..)` sets the list of candidate dates as a sequence from earliest to latest `Date` observed. One reason this is important here is that you expect a row and count on `2023-09-13` despite that date not being observed in the data.

From there, we add a `From` column so that we bound each row's earliest and latest date allowed to join on it. If you look at the data after the `full_join`, you'll see that for each row of the initial `tibble(.)`, we have one or more rows of data, any more than we started with:

```r
tibble(Date = seq(min(out$Date), max(out$Date), by = "day")) %>%
  mutate(From = Date-7) %>%
  full_join(quux, join_by(between(y$Date, x$From, x$Date)))
# # A tibble: 28 × 4
#    Date.x     From          ID Date.y    
#    <date>     <date>     <int> <date>    
#  1 2023-09-10 2023-09-03     1 2023-09-10
#  2 2023-09-10 2023-09-03     2 2023-09-10
#  3 2023-09-11 2023-09-04     1 2023-09-10
#  4 2023-09-11 2023-09-04     2 2023-09-10
#  5 2023-09-11 2023-09-04     7 2023-09-11
#  6 2023-09-12 2023-09-05     1 2023-09-10
#  7 2023-09-12 2023-09-05     2 2023-09-10
#  8 2023-09-12 2023-09-05     7 2023-09-11
#  9 2023-09-12 2023-09-05     8 2023-09-12
# 10 2023-09-12 2023-09-05     1 2023-09-12
# # ℹ 18 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

This is not quite a full "cartesian" join (all of "x" against all of "y"), but it is close enough here with this data. The "join" matches all rows in one frame with those in another frame based on conditions, and our "condition" here is that the second frame's `Date` is between the two dates in the first. (If you want more help on joins *in general*, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272). From there, to learn about "non-equi" or range-based joins, see more at [finding close match from data frame 1 in data fame 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64362881/3358272), [Merging two data frames by time range in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64539945/3358272), [Merge two data frames considering a range match between key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37158839/3358272.))

After that, it is a straight-forward "summarize by group", where the "group" is each of the original tibble's `Date`s, counting the number of distinct `ID`s observed.

Similarly in `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
quuxDT <- as.data.table(quux)
data.table(Date = seq(min(quuxDT$Date), max(quuxDT$Date), by="day")
  )[, c("From", "To") := .(Date-7, Date)
  ][quuxDT, on = .(From <= Date, To >= Date)
  ][, .(count = uniqueN(ID)), by = Date]
#          Date count
#        <Date> <int>
# 1: 2023-09-10     2
# 2: 2023-09-11     3
# 3: 2023-09-12     4
# 4: 2023-09-13     4
# 5: 2023-09-14     4
# 6: 2023-09-15     5
```

The `data.table` package is a little different with regards to its joining columns: in this case we need to duplicate the original reference `Date` into `To` and keep `Date` out of the merge mechanics, so that it is untouched. (If you look at the data immediately after the `[quuxDT, on=.(..)]` joining, you'll see that now `From` and `To` are both the same values; the RHS `Date` values overwrite the LHS `From`/`To` values and then disappears. The reason we have a `Date` column after the join is because it is from the LHS in the first `data.table(Date=..)` call. It's the default behavior for `data.table`, and as wonky as it may appear, it is not changing any time soon.)

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 9L), Date = c(20230910L, 20230910L, 20230911L, 20230912L, 20230912L, 20230914L, 20230915L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here´s another possible `tidyverse` solution without `join`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
df_count <- tribble(
  ~id, ~date,
  1, 20230910,
  2, 20230910,
  7, 20230911,
  8, 20230912,
  1, 20230912,
  7, 20230914,
  9, 20230915)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
df_count <- distinct(df_count, id, .keep_all = TRUE)
df_count <- transmute(df_count, date = ymd(date), count = row_number())
aux <- seq.Date(from = min(df_count$date), to = max(aux$date), by = "day")
df_count <- complete(df_count, date = aux)
df_count <- fill(df_count, count, .direction = "down")

# A tibble: 7 × 2 ---------------------------------------------------------
  date       count
  <date>     <int>
1 2023-09-10     1
2 2023-09-10     2
3 2023-09-11     3
4 2023-09-12     4
5 2023-09-13     4
6 2023-09-14     4
7 2023-09-15     5
```