# Use R to calculate an annual total value between differing dates per year

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframe: 1) Annual onset and cessations dates of the maize growing season, and 2) Daily growing degree data (GDD).

Dataframe one looks like (listed first six lines):

```
Onset_date Year  Cessation_date
366        1950             108
267        1951             124
275        1952             103
296        1953             122
291        1954             117
289        1955             119
```

Dataframe two looks like (listed first and last six lines):

```
Julian_day Year GDD
183        1950   0
184        1950   0
185        1950   0
186        1950   0
187        1950   0
188        1950   0

Julian_day Year GDD
177        2022   0
178        2022   0
179        2022   0
180        2022   0
181        2022   0
182        2022   0
```

From the above data, I need to obtain the total (i.e. sum) of the GDD column as the total value from the onset to the cessation value per year. This sounds like an easy task as one could use the dplyr library to filter the data and then group by year for the calculation of the total value, however, the onset and cessation values differ per year. Therefore, I would like to inquire if anyone can suggest how to calculate the annual GDD total for the growing season, being the GDD total from the onset to the cessation date, for example, the sum of GDD between (and including) day 267 and day 124. I hopeful that there is a simple dplyr option to do this.

I tried to filter my data per year, keeping only the values between and including the onset and cessation dates, but my issue was that these dates are not the same each year. The fact that the dates differ is what I do not know how to account for.

Comment: This can be done with a range-based or non-equi join. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/64362881/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64539945/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37158839/3358272, followed by a summarization.

Comment: Can you explain how the dates are supposed to work? If onset is _after_ cessation, does that mean that the cessation is the next year? Or should we sum from `min(Onset,Cessation)` date to `max(..)` date?

Comment: Thanks for your response @r2evans. I will explore those stackoverflow links and try those options for my problem. As for your question on the dates, I have adapted the 'climatological' year to run from July-June. Thus, for the year 1951, for instance, the onset date is during 1951 while the cessation date is during 1952.

Comment: If `Onset_date` is a julian day, R is saying that `day-of-year 366 in year 1950 is invalid`. How are _you_ defining julian day? Since 1950 is not a leap year, there are only 365 days (ref: https://landweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/ltdr/browse/calendar.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- `Cessation_date` are always `Year+1`
- 1950 is not a leap year, so 366 (first row) is a mistake

This can be done with a non-equi join and a summarize by group. For the join to work, though, we need the updated `Year` for `df1$Cessation` (since it's always "+1") or we add real `Date`-class objects for onset/cessation (`df1`) and julian_day (`df2`). I prefer the latter, it's prone to fewer errors.

I have to generate some sample `df2` since the sample data is all zeros (and `df1` is as-posted).

```r
set.seed(42)
df2 <- data.frame(Julian_day=rep(1:365, times=10)[-(1:182)]) %>%
  mutate(Year = 1950 + cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(Julian_day) < 0)),
         GDD = sample(10, size = n(), replace = TRUE))
head(df2)
#   Julian_day Year GDD       date
# 1        183 1950   1 1950-07-02
# 2        184 1950   5 1950-07-03
# 3        185 1950   1 1950-07-04
# 4        186 1950   9 1950-07-05
# 5        187 1950  10 1950-07-06
# 6        188 1950   4 1950-07-07
```

```r
library(dplyr)
# create `Date`-class, you can remove this `date` after the join if you prefer
df2 <- mutate(df2, date = as.Date(paste(Year, Julian_day), format = "%Y %j"))

df1 %>%
  # 1950 doesn't have a julian day 366, hack, check your data
  mutate(across(c(Onset_date, Cessation_date),
                ~ if_else(lubridate::leap_year(Year), .x, pmin(.x, 365)))) %>%
  # resume "normal" operation from here
  mutate(
    Onset_date2 = as.Date(paste(Year, Onset_date), format = "%Y %j"),
    Cessation_date2 = as.Date(paste(Year+1, Cessation_date), format = "%Y %j")
  ) %>%
  left_join(select(df2, date, GDD),
            join_by(between(y$date, x$Onset_date2, x$Cessation_date2))) %>%
  summarize(GDD = sum(GDD), .by = names(df1))
#   Onset_date Year Cessation_date  GDD
# 1        365 1950            108  642
# 2        267 1951            124 1167
# 3        275 1952            103 1089
# 4        296 1953            122 1002
# 5        291 1954            117 1025
# 6        289 1955            119 1102
```

If both of your frames are "large" (subjective), this might become a memory problem, in which case @-ping me and we'll work on a (much) slower but more memory-frugal method.

---

Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Onset_date = c(366L, 267L, 275L, 296L, 291L, 289L), Year = 1950:1955, Cessation_date = c(108L, 124L, 103L, 122L, 117L, 119L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
## df2 as created, above
```