# Use time data from one data to retrieve data from another set

Tags: python, r, database, matlab, csv

I am working with two tab-delimited files. One has labels with time stamps, and the other has time stamps with pitch tracking data. Samples of both below.

**Label file (table A)**

```
12011.151   12133.975   statusAE1
12168.452   12239.561   statusAH0
14500.971   14616.253   statusAE1
14649.114   14702.446   statusAH0
16827.322   16943.682   statusAE1
16978.159   17028.797   statusAH0
19632.974   19688.999   purposeER1
19787.582   19847.916   purposeAH0
21957.925   22028.293   purposeER1
```

The first column above is start time, in milliseconds, the second is the end time, and the third is the label of the defined region.

**Pitch data (table B)**

```
479.002 41.565
503.039 60.425
521.905 0.000
2161.905    171.387
2167.710    0.000
2175.147    143.646
2182.132    143.494
2188.844    143.646
2195.828    144.714
2202.812    144.806
2209.705    144.287
2216.599    143.433
2223.583    143.768
2230.476    144.043
2237.551    144.836
```

The first column is time in milliseconds, and the second is fundamental frequency (f0) in Hertz. I would like to write a script that will compare these tables and create a new table, such that any row in table B that is within a time sequence defined in table A will be listed with the following format:

```
time f0 label
```

I'm hoping to do this within R. I would also be willing to try python or MATLAB solutions.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window/25655497#25655497)

Answer (score 1):

Here is with a crossjoin

```
library(dplyr)

pitch %>%
  merge(label) %>%
  filter(start_time <= time & time <= end_time)
```

Comment: Thanks I will look give that a try