# R index and match with multiple conditions

Tags: r, match

I have 2 lists which I wish to merge on R. Basically I wish to compare one column `Chr` on both lists, and if the values match, then compare another column  on the first list to see whether that value lies between two columns of the second list.

So:

List1

```
Probe Chr Pos
abc1 1 1000
abc2 1 1200
abc3 1 23000
abd1 2 1023
```

List2

```
Ref Chr Start End
adam 1 800 999
ben 1 1150 1210
cary 3 2000 3000
danny 5 3023 3400
```

Product

```
Probe Chr Pos Ref Start End
abc2 1 1200 ben 1150 1210
```

I was thinking perhaps `merge(List1, List2, by="Chr")` then some sort of `ifelse` filter on `Product$Ref` and `Product[,c("Start","End")]`. As usual, thousands of lines per list are involved so a neater alternative would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can try `foverlaps` from `library(data.table)`

Comment: I think [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window/25655497#25655497) is useful here. Especially note the `d2[, pos2 := pos]` step, where you make an 'interval' from a single position ("_special case of such an overlap join, where the start and end coordinates are identical for d2_"), analogous to your "Pos" in "List1".