# Add column to dataframe depending on specific row values

Tags: r, dataframe, addition

I am trying to solve something that for me is a problem since a few days.

Here an example of my data.frame, which I hope will work with my real one.

```
df <- read.table(text = 'ID    Day Count
    33012   9526    4
    35004   9526    4
    37006   9526    4
    37008   9526    4
    21009   1913    3
    24005   1913    3
    25009   1913    3
    22317   2286    2
    37612   2286    2
    25009   14329   1
    48007   9525    0
    88662   9524    0
    1845    9524    0
    8872    2285    0
    49002   1912    0
    1664    1911    0', header = TRUE)
```

I need to add a new column (`new_col`) to my data.frame which contains values from 1 to 4. These `new_col` values have to include, each one, day (x) day (x -1) and day (x -2), where x = 9526, 1913, 2286, 14329 (column `Day`).

My output should be the following:

```
   ID    Day Count  new_col
33012   9526    4     1
35004   9526    4     1
37006   9526    4     1
37008   9526    4     1
21009   1913    3     2
24005   1913    3     2
25009   1913    3     2
22317   2286    2     3
37612   2286    2     3
25009   14329   1     4
48007   9525    0     1
88662   9524    0     1
1845    9524    0     1
8872    2285    0     3
49002   1912    0     2
1664    1911    0     2
```

The data.frame ordered by `new_col` will be then:

```
   ID    Day Count  new_col
33012   9526    4     1
35004   9526    4     1
37006   9526    4     1
37008   9526    4     1
48007   9525    0     1
88662   9524    0     1
1845    9524    0     1
21009   1913    3     2
24005   1913    3     2
25009   1913    3     2
49002   1912    0     2
1664    1911    0     2
22317   2286    2     3
37612   2286    2     3
8872    2285    0     3
25009   14329   1     4
```

My real data.frame is more complex than the example (i.e. more columns and more values in the `Count` column, therefore be patient if I will update the question.

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but it seems like you could use `cut()` to achieve this, as follows:

```
x <- c(1913, 2286, 9526, 14329) 
df$new_col <- cut(df$Day, c(-Inf, x, Inf))
df$new_col <- as.numeric(factor(df$new_col, levels=unique(df$new_col)))
```

Comment: I would give 1'000 points if only I could. thanks :) your code not only works with x, x-1 and x-2 but with all the days prior x (maybe due to the fact of c(-Inf, x, Inf)). anyway..thanks again

Comment: hi, I just posted a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847645/add-column-to-dataframe-depending-on-specific-row-values-2 which maybe you can answer easily. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non scalable but easy to understand solution using `dplyr` package, we can use `case_when` to recode the Day based on the condition:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(new_col = case_when(abs(df$Day - 9526) <= 2 ~ 1,
                                  abs(df$Day - 1913) <= 2 ~ 2,
                                  abs(df$Day - 2286)<= 2 ~ 3,
                                  abs(df$Day - 14329) <= 2 ~ 4)) %>%
    arrange(new_col)

#       ID   Day Count new_col
# 1  33012  9526     4       1
# 2  35004  9526     4       1
# 3  37006  9526     4       1
# 4  37008  9526     4       1
# 5  48007  9525     0       1
# 6  88662  9524     0       1
# 7   1845  9524     0       1
# 8  21009  1913     3       2
# 9  24005  1913     3       2
# 10 25009  1913     3       2
# 11 49002  1912     0       2
# 12  1664  1911     0       2
# 13 22317  2286     2       3
# 14 37612  2286     2       3
# 15  8872  2285     0       3
# 16 25009 14329     1       4
```

A more scalable approach would be to use `foverlaps` from `data.table` package, where we prepare a look up table and then join back with the original table and use `within` type join to make sure the days are in the range specified in the look up table, for better explanation about [foverlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window)

```
library(data.table)
# prepare the look up table
x <- c(9526, 1913, 2286, 14329)
dt1 <- data.table(start = x - 2, end = x, new_col = 1:4)
setkey(dt1)
dt1
#    start   end new_col
# 1:  1911  1913       2
# 2:  2284  2286       3
# 3:  9524  9526       1
# 4: 14327 14329       4

# prepare the original table
dt = copy(setDT(df))
dt[, Day2 := Day]

# do a foverlaps
foverlaps(dt, dt1, by.x = c("Day", "Day2"), by.y = c("start", "end"), type = "within", mult = "all", nomatch = 0L)[, .(ID, Day, Count, new_col)][order(new_col)]

#       ID   Day Count new_col
# 1  33012  9526     4       1
# 2  35004  9526     4       1
# 3  37006  9526     4       1
# 4  37008  9526     4       1
# 5  48007  9525     0       1
# 6  88662  9524     0       1
# 7   1845  9524     0       1
# 8  21009  1913     3       2
# 9  24005  1913     3       2
# 10 25009  1913     3       2
# 11 49002  1912     0       2
# 12  1664  1911     0       2
# 13 22317  2286     2       3
# 14 37612  2286     2       3
# 15  8872  2285     0       3
# 16 25009 14329     1       4
```

Comment: hi, your code works perfectly with the example, but not with my real dataframe and this makes me really frustrated