# map chromosome positions in gene ranges code in R

Tags: r

I have two files one contains the specific chromosome position and other contains the gene_name and gene's start to end range. I have to find the gene name by matching the in-between start to end position of the genes to position of chromosome.Format of my 1st file is like below
    `Chromosome Position
       1         394
       1         447
       2         534`

Format of my 2nd file is:

```
gene_name  chromoome  start  end
   pqr         1       201   230
   sbc         1       300   450
   ffg         2       500   550
```

I have tried the following code

```
setwd('/home/R/')
data = read.table(file='outfile.tsv', fill = TRUE)
data1 = read.table(file='Sample.tsv')
chr = data1[,1]
pos = data1[,2]
gene = data[,1]
beg = data[,3]
end = data[,4]

pos_sz = dim.data.frame(pos)
beg_sz = dim.data.frame(beg)
end_sz = dim.data.frame(end)

for (i in 1:length(pos))
{
pos_1 = pos[i]
x = pos_1>=beg & pos_1<=end
print(x)
if(any(x == "TRUE"))
{
t=pos[i]
print(t)
s = which(pos == t)
print(s)
v= chr[s]
print(v)
}
y=which(c(x))
print(y)
z=gene[y]
print(z)
}
```

I want result in below format

```
gene_name   Chromosome   #chromosome against position
sbc              1
sbc              1
ffg              2
```

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Your below format just has the column names. What's your desired output?

Comment: Related: [roll join with start/end window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `GenomicRanges` package

```
library(GenomicRanges)
# data
target <- read.table(text="gene_name  chromoome  start  end
   pqr         1       201   230
   sbc         1       300   450
   ffg         2       500   550", header=T)

# set up GRange objects
d <- GRanges(c(1,1,2), IRanges(c(394,447,534), width=1))
target_range <- GRanges(target$chromoome, IRanges(start=target$start, end=target$end))

# get overlaps
OL <- findOverlaps(d, target_range)
target[as.data.frame(OL)[,2],]
    gene_name chromoome start end
2         sbc         1   300 450
2.1       sbc         1   300 450
3         ffg         2   500 550
```

Or by merging

```
# merge
target_range <- GRanges(target$chromoome, IRanges(start=target$start, end=target$end), names=target$gene_name)
mergeByOverlaps(d, target_range)
DataFrame with 3 rows and 3 columns
          d target_range    names
  <GRanges>    <GRanges> <factor>
1 1:394-394    1:300-450      sbc
2 1:447-447    1:300-450      sbc
3 2:534-534    2:500-550      ffg
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but I have around 40000 genes and then it's not possible for me to put in vectors.

Comment: @KritikaRajain Why? I'm using this code to map genomewide expression and genotyping data with hundredthousands of genes and markers without problems.

Comment: thanks for your concern. Yes I managed via using sql package.