# Expand range of dates by group based on 2 other columns-

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I need to merge two tables by zip codes such that date ranges from table, *ID_dates* should contain the ranges in table, *zipcodes*.

Description of data:

Table *ID_dates* gives pre and post that covers the entire range of dates for *ID_dates*.
Combination of ID and pre gives a unique combination for the group within which the ranges in zip codes must lie.
Ranges in *ID_dates* are continuous with no gaps.
Zipcode is string but I am unable to have R read as a character in my example below (I am new to R so please forgive my mistakes in the code below,if any)

The ranges in *zipcodes* do not cover the range of pre and post. The ranges in *zipcodes* may lie outside of the pre and post dates in *ID_dates* and hence the start and end dates of *zipcodes* where this happens have to be truncated. For each group (combination of zip code and ID), the endpoints are pre and post.

```
zipcodes <- read.table(text="
zipcode  start         end      var1
08210   03/15/1992   03/29/1992 1
08210   06/29/1993   06/30/1993 2
07039   03/28/1992   03/31/1992 5
07046   06/6/1994    06/6/1994  1
", colClasses='character',header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

zipcodes$start   <- as.Date(zipcodes$start,format = "%m/%d/%y")
zipcodes$end     <- as.Date(zipcodes$end,format = "%m/%d/%y")
    

ID_dates <- read.table(text="
ID  zipcode    t1       t2          pre       post    var2
A   08210   03/17/1992  03/28/1992  03/17/1992  06/01/1993  1
A   08210   03/29/1992  04/05/1992  03/17/1992  06/01/1993  2
A   07039   04/06/1992  06/01/1993  03/17/1992  06/01/1993  3
A   07046   07/07/1995  08/07/1995  07/07/1995  08/07/1995  5
B   90002   01/01/1996  02/01/1996  01/01/1996  02/01/1996  8
", colClasses='character',header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

ID_dates$t1   <- as.Date(ID_dates$t1,format = "%m/%d/%y")
ID_dates$t2     <- as.Date(ID_dates$t2,format = "%m/%d/%y")
ID_dates$pre     <- as.Date(ID_dates$pre,format = "%m/%d/%y")
ID_dates$post     <- as.Date(ID_dates$post,format = "%m/%d/%y")



finaltable <- read.table(text="
id   zipcode   t1           t2     var1  var2
A   08210   03/17/1992  03/28/1992  1   1
A   08210   03/29/1992  04/05/1992  NA  2
A   07039   04/06/1992  06/01/1993  NA  3
A   07046   07/07/1995  08/07/1995  NA  5
B   90002   01/01/1996  02/01/1996  NA  8
  ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I am unable to write a code to achieve the above result.

Comment: @Ronak Thanks Ronak.  I have fixed the errors.

Comment: @RonakShah I have made the edits.  I too got the same error and the same code worked fine with other data frames. Not sure why...

Comment: I see. Thanks for the update. Have you tried answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/overlap-join-with-start-and-end-positions This question looks very similar.