# any recommend for finding the intersection of two continuous variable in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation

How can I find the intersection percentages of some continuous variables, see the example below, please?

```
d1<-data.frame(Start=c(10, 8, 6, 4 ), End=c(14, 12, 9,17 ))
```

I want to check each row of the columns A and B overlap with the rest of the row, instead of for loop? For example,

```
d1[1,] %overlaps% d1[2,]
```

and `d1[1,] %overlaps% d1[3,]`and ..finally, `d3[1,] %overlaps% d4[3,]`

How to do that?

Comment: What's the desired output here? And what exactly do you mean by "overlaps"? Is that different from `%in%`? Are you just looking for duplicated rows?

Comment: you can think the columns as start and end point

Comment: try `intersect()`

Comment: Ok, but how to compare each row with the other rows? For example, row 1 and row2, row1 and row3, row 1 and row 4, then row2 and row3..

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/24480031/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following determines if one segment in the real line defined by the endpoints `Start` and `End` overlaps another segment. The row combinations are created with `combn` and an anonymous function is applied to each combination.

```
`%overlaps%` <- function(X, Y){
  f <- function(x, y){
    a1 <- x[1] <= y[1] && y[1] <= x[2]
    a2 <- x[1] <= y[2] && y[2] <= x[2]
    a1 || a2
  }
  f(X, Y) || f(Y, X)
}

combn(1:nrow(d1), 2, function(x) {
  d1[x[1], ] %overlaps% d1[x[2], ]
})
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Start` in `d1` has been given in a descending order, you only need to check if `End` values of next intervals are greater than the current `Start` value, e.g.,

```
> unlist(sapply(1:(nrow(d1)-1),function(k) d1$End[-(1:k)]>=d1$Start[k]))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```