# Merge dataframes based on intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame("id"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                  "date"=c(10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15))

df2 <- data.frame("id"=c(1, 1, 2),
                  "startDate"=c(9, 14, 9),
                  "endDate"=c(10, 15, 10),
                  "value"=c(99, 100, 10))
```

I would like to merge `df2` on to `df1` on the `id`-column and the date-column such that a given `date` in `df1` is larger than `startDate` or less than or equal to `endDate`. If the date in `df1` isn't in the interval dictated by `df2` for that particular `id`, then it should just be a NA. The resulting dataframe should be

```
df <- data.frame("id"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 "date"=c(10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15),
                 "value"=c(99, 100, NA, NA, 10, NA))
```

In essence it is a left-join I want on `id` and `date`, but where the `date` of `df2` is an interval.

Comment: Try this non-equi join solution using `data.table` https://stackoverflow.com/a/38394201

Comment: You can join in any order. This gives your expected output after you turn the two dataframe to datatable `df2[df1, on=.(id, startDate <= date, endDate >= date)]`