# Integrate two data frame giving a position and using an interval in R

Tags: r

I need to do the following process using R:
1)I have a df1 that looks

| Chrom | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 30 |
| 1 | 50 | 80 |
| 1 | 100 | 140 |
| 2 | 20 | 40 |
| 2 | 60 | 100 |
| 2 | 110 | 130 |

2)And a df2 that looks

| Chrom | TAG | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AX-1020 | 55 |
| 2 | AX-1320 | 75 |

3)So, I would like to add info from df2 into df1 using the interval between Start and End in df1 and Position in df2 as I show here

| Chrom | Start | End | TAG | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 30 | NA | NA |
| 1 | 50 | 80 | AX-1020 | 55 |
| 1 | 100 | 140 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 20 | 40 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 60 | 100 | AX-1320 | 75 |
| 2 | 110 | 130 | NA | NA |

I hope anyone can help me. I'd appreaciate a lot!

Comment: Nice post on this topic: [Overlap join with start and end positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/overlap-join-with-start-and-end-positions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also `data.table`

```
library( data.table )
#read sample data as data.tables
df1 <- fread("Chrom     Start   End
1   0   30
1   50  80
1   100     140
2   20  40
2   60  100
2   110     130")
df2 <- fread("Chrom     TAG     Position
1   AX-1020     55
2   AX-1320     75")

#update non-equi join
df1[ df2, `:=`(TAG = i.TAG, 
               Position = i.Position ), 
     on = .(Chrom, Start <= Position, End >= Position) ][]
#    Chrom Start End     TAG Position
# 1:     1     0  30    <NA>       NA
# 2:     1    50  80 AX-1020       55
# 3:     1   100 140    <NA>       NA
# 4:     2    20  40    <NA>       NA
# 5:     2    60 100 AX-1320       75
# 6:     2   110 130    <NA>       NA
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but you seem to make a left join, while I perform a join by reference.