# Reorder data.table with variable columns

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like this:

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | subtotal | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 001 | 001 | 10 | 100 |
| 001 | 001 | 001 | 002 | 5 | 20 |
| 001 | 002 | 001 | 001 | 10 | 200 |

Using shiny I can then select which ID's I want to group by, for example ID1 till ID3:

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | subtotal | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 001 | 15 | 120 |
| 001 | 002 | 001 | 10 | 200 |

As you can see the first row of this table is a sum of the first two rows of the first table.

I then calculate the percentage, the column will automatically be put at the very end:

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | subtotal | total | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 001 | 15 | 120 | 12.5 |
| 001 | 002 | 001 | 10 | 200 | 5 |

However, I would like see this column just after the IDs.

I tried to use `setcolorder` however the columns can vary depending on which IDs are selected. The IDs that are used are stored in a vector which I tried to use like so:

```
dt[, .(vector, percentage, subtotal, total)]
```

and:

```
dt[, c(vector, "percentage", "subtotal", "total")]
```

but neither option worked

for reference (keep in mind that it should work for any combination of IDs):

```
dput(vector)
c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlap join with start and end positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/overlap-join-with-start-and-end-positions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the solution after toying around more with `setcolorder`:

```
setcolorder(dt, c(vector, "percentage", colnames(dt)[!(colnames(dt) %in% vector) & !(colnames(dt) == "percentage")]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following solution using `dplyr` will work for you. It will put the percent column immediately following all columns matching the `"id"` pattern. The actual re-ordering of columns happens in the `relocate()` call.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id1, id2, id3) %>%
  summarise(subtotal = sum(subtotal),
            total = sum(total),
            percent = subtotal / total * 100) %>%
  relocate(percent, .after = contains("id"))

  id1   id2   id3   percent subtotal total
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 001   001   001      12.5       15   120
2 001   002   001       5         10   200
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This would generally be what I am looking for except that I would like to keep it in `data.table` format rather than going back to `data.frame`

Comment: Would it be acceptable to re-convert it after `relocate()`? You could add another pipe and use `data.table()`.

Comment: I was thinking about doing so however in the same moment I figured out another way of doing it without `dplyr` so I will stick to that

Comment: Fair enough. No need to make large changes if you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

With [*development* version 1.14.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), `setcolorder()` has gained the new arguments `before` as well as `after` to indicate the position to insert a column:

```
setcolorder(dt, "percentage", before = "subtotal")
dt
```

> ```
>    ID1 ID2 ID3 percentage subtotal total
> 1:   1   1   1       12.5       15   120
> 2:   1   2   1        5.0       10   200
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("
ID1 ID2 ID3 subtotal    total   percentage
001 001 001 15  120 12.5
001 002 001 10  200 5")
```