# Need to insert various rows of data from a data frame after particular rows from another data frame

Tags: r

I have dataset in a particular format in "dacnet_yield_update till 2019.xlsx" file, where I need to insert the data of rows 2018-2019 and 2019-2020 for the districts those data are available in "Kharif crops yield_18-19.xlsx".  I need to insert these two rows of data belonging to every district, if data is available in a later excel file, just after the particular crop group data for the particular district.

```
my_data <- data.frame(
crop = c(arhar, arhar, rice, moong),
season_name = rep(kharif, 4),
state_id= c(1204, 1205, 1204, 1206),
state_name= c(Asam,Bihar, Asam, Orrisa),
district_name= c(Jorhat, Patna, Naagaon, Puri),
district_id = c(15016, 16312, 15089, 17032),
year_id = c(2016, 2015, 2017, 2017),
yield= c(0.86, 1.23, 0.96, 1.05))
```

2nd excel sheet has same dataframe but I need to get the 2018 and 2019  yeardID data from here and insert after same district for same crop in a state.

```
`my_2nd_data <- data.frame(
crop = c(arhar, arhar, rice, moong),
season_name = rep(kharif, 4),
state_id= c(1204, 1205, 1204, 1206),
state_name= c(Asam,Bihar, Asam, Orrisa),
district_name= c(Jorhat, Patna, Naagaon, Puri),
district_id = c(15016, 16312, 15089, 17032),
year_id = c(2018, 2018, 2019, 2018),
yield= c(0.96, 1.16, 0.99, 1.12))`
```

So, the rows of 2018 and 2019 for a particular crop for from "my_2nd_data" I need to insert in first dataframe after row of same district under a state. This should look like the attached image.[image]

I have put the data file in the given link.
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1dNmGTI8_c9PK1QqmfIjnpbyzuiCXgxFC

Comment: Please share a reproducible example using ``dput()``.

Comment: You might find some useful ideas for joining data frames here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24480031/8400969

Comment: Hi @user438383...added reproducible example.

Comment: Hi @Michael...Tried but not getting sense..nothing working

Comment: @RJ34 images aren't reproducible. Please use ``dput()``.

Comment: Please include small sample data in the question, not a link to external data to download.`dput()` is a great command for making a copy/pasteable version of a data frame, use, e.g., `dput(my_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows of a data frame named `my_data`. It will be copy/pasteable and include all class and structure information. Choose a few suitable rows to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @user438383...added dataframe

Comment: @GregorThomas..added reproducible data

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go with a `rbind()` followed by a sorting, considering `df1` and `df2` your 2 dataframes :

```
df3=rbind(df1,df2)
df3=df3[order(df3$district,df3$year),]
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(df3,"df3.xlsx")
```

Comment: @Basti...it throws error...Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Comment: In the example you gave, both dataframes had the same column names. Check that your dataframes have the same column names to make it work

Comment: Please check the files in the given link. Actually, I am having more issues before binding the rows. To come to final step there are data cleaning needs to be done, which I am unable to do because of not proper pattern of data.

Comment: You provided two examples dataframe and my answer is dedicated to. There are 12+ files in your link. You will need to format your dataframes. If you have issues, please open a new post because this is not the same question that was formerly asked