# Assign groups in dataframe using vectors containing start and end indexes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(X = LETTERS[1:20], 
                 Y = paste0("abc_", 1:20))
#  X     Y
#1 A abc_1
#2 B abc_2
#3 C abc_3
#4 D abc_4
#5 E abc_5
#6 F abc_6
# ...
```

I need to assign group ID based on two vectors of integers. One indicates where the group starts, the other indicates where the group ends:

```
start_ix <- c(2, 5, 8, 10, 15, 18)
end_ix   <- c(4, 7, 9, 13, 17, 19)
```

i.e. the first group is rows 2 through 4, the second is row 5 through 7, and so on. Any row not contained in these indexes (or the span between the start and stop values) should be `NA`.

The desired outcome would be:

```
df_want <- structure(list(X = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"), 
    Y = c("abc_1", "abc_2", "abc_3", "abc_4", "abc_5", "abc_6", 
    "abc_7", "abc_8", "abc_9", "abc_10", "abc_11", "abc_12", 
    "abc_13", "abc_14", "abc_15", "abc_16", "abc_17", "abc_18", 
    "abc_19", "abc_20"), grp = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, NA, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = "data.frame")

#    X      Y grp
# 1  A  abc_1  NA
# 2  B  abc_2   1
# 3  C  abc_3   1
# 4  D  abc_4   1
# 5  E  abc_5   2
# 6  F  abc_6   2
# 7  G  abc_7   2
# 8  H  abc_8   3
# 9  I  abc_9   3
# 10 J abc_10   4
# 11 K abc_11   4
# 12 L abc_12   4
# 13 M abc_13   4
# 14 N abc_14  NA
# 15 O abc_15   5
# 16 P abc_16   5
# 17 Q abc_17   5
# 18 R abc_18   6
# 19 S abc_19   6
# 20 T abc_20  NA
```

**The solution in my specific case would need to be done in base R**, but for the sake of others who may have the same issue feel free to post solutions from external packages.

I have tried a combination of indexing, sorting, and `seq` but can't seem to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *base* method using `sequence`.

```
. <- 1 + end_ix - start_ix
df[sequence(., start_ix), "grp"] <- rep(seq_along(.), .)
```

Another *base* methode using `Map`.

```
. <- Map(seq, start_ix, end_ix)
df[unlist(.), "grp"] <- rep(seq_along(.), lengths(.))
```

---

Benchmark

```
bench::mark(
jpsmith = local({seqV <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("to", "from"))
  ix <- unlist(seqV(start_ix, end_ix))
  df[ix, "grp"] <- rep(1:length(start_ix), (end_ix - start_ix) + 1)
  df}),
zx8754 = local({for(i in seq_along(start_ix)){
  df[ start_ix[ i ]:end_ix[ i ], "grp"] <- i}
  df}),
GKiSeq = local({. <- 1 + end_ix - start_ix
  df[sequence(., start_ix), "grp"] <- rep(seq_along(.), .)
  df}),
GKiMap = local({. <- Map(seq, start_ix, end_ix)
  df[unlist(.), "grp"] <- rep(seq_along(.), lengths(.))
  df})
)
#  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 jpsmith     186.1µs 198.4µs   4944.    280B    12.3  2408     6   487ms <df>  
#2 zx8754      212.4µs 226.6µs   4339.    280B    12.4  2095     6   483ms <df>  
#3 GKiSeq       60.6µs  67.1µs  14679.    280B    12.3  7160     6   488ms <df>  
#4 GKiMap        103µs 111.6µs   8748.    280B    12.3  4265     6   488ms <df>
```

Answer (score 1):

While there may be better solutions, one potential solution which `Vectorize`s the `seq` function to index the rows, then uses a vector from the difference in start and end positions in `rep` to identify the groups:

```
#Index
seqV <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("to", "from"))
ix <- unlist(seqV(start_ix, end_ix))

#Assign groups
df[ix, "grp"] <- rep(1:length(start_ix), (end_ix - start_ix) + 1)

# Validate
all.equal(df_want, df)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *for* loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(start_ix)){
  df[ start_ix[ i ]:end_ix[ i ], "grp"] <- i
  }
```

Another option, [range overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24480031/680068), using *data.table::foverlaps*:

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- cbind(data.table(start = seq(nrow(df)), end = seq(nrow(df))), df)
df2 <- data.table(start = start_ix, end = end_ix, grp = seq_along(start_ix))

setkey(df1, start, end)
setkey(df2, start, end)

foverlaps(df1, df2)[, .(X, Y, group)]
#     X      Y   grp
#  1: A  abc_1    NA
#  2: B  abc_2     1
#  3: C  abc_3     1
#  4: D  abc_4     1
#  5: E  abc_5     2
#  etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` option might be:

```
ids_lst <- map2(start_ix, end_ix, seq)

df %>%
 mutate(grp = map_int(row_number(), 
                      function(rowid) match(TRUE, map2_lgl(rowid, ids_lst, function(rowid, ids) rowid %in% ids), nomatch = NA)))

   X      Y grp
1  A  abc_1  NA
2  B  abc_2   1
3  C  abc_3   1
4  D  abc_4   1
5  E  abc_5   2
6  F  abc_6   2
7  G  abc_7   2
8  H  abc_8   3
9  I  abc_9   3
10 J abc_10   4
11 K abc_11   4
12 L abc_12   4
13 M abc_13   4
14 N abc_14  NA
15 O abc_15   5
16 P abc_16   5
17 Q abc_17   5
18 R abc_18   6
19 S abc_19   6
20 T abc_20  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully vectorized base R solution, using indexing, `findInterval`, and `rbind`:

```
df$grp <- rbind(NA, 1:nrow(df))[
  findInterval(
    1:nrow(df),
    c(
      rbind(
        start_ix,
        end_ix + 0.1
      )
    )
  ) + 1L
]
```

Adding to the benchmark from @GKi:

```
bench::mark(
  jpsmith = local({seqV <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("to", "from"))
  ix <- unlist(seqV(start_ix, end_ix))
  df[ix, "grp"] <- rep(1:length(start_ix), (end_ix - start_ix) + 1)
  df}),
  zx8754 = local({for(i in seq_along(start_ix)){
    df[ start_ix[ i ]:end_ix[ i ], "grp"] <- i}
    df}),
  GKiSeq = local({. <- 1 + end_ix - start_ix
  df[sequence(., start_ix), "grp"] <- rep(seq_along(.), .)
  df}),
  GKiMap = local({. <- Map(seq, start_ix, end_ix)
  df[unlist(.), "grp"] <- rep(seq_along(.), lengths(.))
  df}),
  jblood94 = local({
    df$grp <- rbind(NA, 1:nrow(df))[
      findInterval(
        1:nrow(df),
        c(
          rbind(
            start_ix,
            end_ix + 0.1
          )
        )
      ) + 1L
    ]
    df}
  )
)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 jpsmith      93.6µs  104.2µs     9227.   46.03KB    116. 
#> 2 zx8754       95.4µs  101.9µs     9443.      280B     27.6
#> 3 GKiSeq       28.3µs   30.2µs    32045.    5.68KB     28.9
#> 4 GKiMap       56.4µs   59.7µs    16332.      280B     29.6
#> 5 jblood94     16.4µs   17.7µs    54828.   16.98KB     32.9
```