# R - Compare two columns of a dataframe with three columns of another

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

Imagine I have a dataframe with addresses (1 column: Street Name, 2nd: Street Nr).
I also have a second dataframe where a range of important addresses is noted (3 columns: Street Name, 2nd Street Starting Nr, 3rd: Street End Nr)

[dataframes structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw8hj.png)

I want to find, if an address within the 1st dataframe is within the range of addresses in the 2nd dataframe.

So street name in the 1st dataframe has to fit with the street name in the 2nd and - if this happens to be the case - the street number has to be within the range of the 2nd dataframe.

With the above example, Halley is an important street and the number 25 is within the range of 20-27 and get a value YES.

My first dataframe has ~7000 rows, the second has ~200.

How could I do this?

I tried with a for loop and with dplyr mutate, although I am not sure this is the best way.

Comment: Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/overlap-join-with-start-and-end-positions

Answer (score 0):

Combine `left_join()`, `mutate()` and [`case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) for the desired result:

```
library(tidyverse)

# replicate 'df1':
df1 <- tibble(Street = c('Halley', 'Halley', 'Wall'),
              Nr = c(25, 30, 21))

# replicate 'df2':
df2 <- tibble(Street = c('Halley', 'Inkling', 'Rawling'),
              Start = c(20, 10, 2),
              End = c(27, 16, 7))

# join & conditionally mutate:
df3 <- df1 |>
  left_join(df2, by = 'Street') |>
  mutate(`In Range` = case_when(Nr >= Start & Nr <= End ~ 'Y',
                                T ~ 'N'))
```

Comment: Hello. First of all, thank you for offering to help. I tried this code but does not work. I remain with the 2 dataframes, exactly as they were in the beginning.

Comment: Hello - I have edited the code to reassign the result of the join/ mutate to a new dataframe (df3). Are you able to re-run and report back?